# Are there any gameplay differences between the male and female Shepard?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I finished Mass Effect 2 on the hardest setting with both a male and female Shepard and I'm not sure which one I want to import first.  Are there any differences for male and female Shepard in Mass Effect 3 ***BESIDES*** possible love interests?  Any pros/cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **No.**

There are no major differences between a male and female Shepard other than romance options, and an occasional minor dialog (think of the condescending mercs on Omega during the *Dossier:Archangel* mission in ME2).

The major difference between the two comes down to the voice actor and romance paths.

Comment: WOW that was a big font lol o.O

Comment: And let's face it: Jennifer > Mark.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Certainly for Renegade dialog, it's a no brainer. Hale blows him away. Male Shepard sounds downright wooden when he tries to be a reckless win at all costs type.

Comment: Also important to point out, your access to the male or female washroom is appropriately restricted on board the Normandy.

Comment: This is the 22nd century. You'd think that on a military spaceship where sleeping with aliens is okay a co-ed bathroom would be the order of the day... especially with space generally being at a premium!